# cannot import name '_ClassNamePrefixFeaturesOutMixin' from 'sklearn.base' (C:\Users\yunhu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having trouble because of
cannot import name '_ClassNamePrefixFeaturesOutMixin' from 'sklearn.base' (C:\Users\yunhu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py)
and I have no clue how to solve this problem. I uninstalled and then installed sklearn again
but It still does not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This issue occurs when i am trying this import statement -- 
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing trying to import SMOTE in a Jupyter notebook (after having just installed imblearn).
Restarting the kernel solved it.